# What are good and bad ways to document a software project?

Tags: documentation

I'm responsible of finding a good way to document the software project I'm working on.

What things are important to document? Should documentation of code and design mainly be in the code in the form of comments? Should we put text files or Word documents directly in the source control togetether with code? Should we use a wiki?

Factors to think about include how easy it is for the current team to create the documentation, and how easy it is for other developers to find, correct and extend the documentation later. My experience from many projects is that developers tend to not write documentation because the system for writing it is too complex or developer unfriendly, and that after a few years, new developers can hardly find the little documentation that was written.

I'm interested in what approaches you have used in similar projects. What worked well, what did not work well, and why?

Some key facts about the project:

- The platform is C# and .NET.
- We use Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server for source control and work item (task) management.
- We use Scrum and test-driven development and are inspired by domain-driven design.
- The software consists of a collection of web services and two GUI clients.
- Other clients are going to integrate with the web services in the future. The integration will be done by other developers on other teams (so the web services form a kind of API).
- SharePoint is heavily used throughout the development environment. Most projects have a SharePoint site, including ours.
- On our project's SharePoint site we currently have a bunch of MS Office documents on things like requirements, design, presentations for stakeholders etc. Keeping everything up to date is hard.
- We also have a SharePoint wiki for the development team only, where we document things in an unstructured manner as we go along. Examples include how our build scripts are organized, our testing policy, coding guidelines.
- The software is an in-house application in a fairly big financial institution.
- The software is developed by a team of six people over a period of ~1 year.
- The developers are consultants hired in for this project only, and will not be available to help in the future (unless the client decides to pay for it).
- The client has few guidlines for how this kind of project should be documented.

Comment: Please examine these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation.  Which of these apply to your situation? How is your situation different from these?  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501074/recommendations-for-documentation-with-an-open-source-project

Comment: Many of these are relevant, but I think it's useful to restart the the discussion of this topic once in a while. Also, a lot of the discussion revolves around which tools to use for doc generation etc. I'm more interested in the concepts, why some approaches work and why other fail.

Comment: @jonsb: Please do not "restart the topic" by asking the same question again.  Please update the existing questions with new information.   Please reference the existing questions.  Simply re-asking an existing question is rude.  We've already answered it.

Comment: @s.lott: "Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. If you end up asking a question that has been asked before, that is OK and deliberately allowed." - faq

Answer (score 12):

I think the most important things to document are the *decisions*. This goes for everything from requirements to architectural choices. What are the requirements of module X? How are these requirements represented in the architecture? Why did you choose architectural pattern A over B? What are the benefits? The same goes for source code: it is common knowledge that commenting the *why* is way better than the *how*.

How you document these decisions does not matter that much in my opinion, whether you use a Wiki or a Requirements document made in Word. More important is that these documents are always up-to-date and that it is easy for anyone to access them. This can be achieved by using a wiki, or placing the documents under source control, as you say. If only a few have access to them, they are more likely not to get updated, and not to be read when necessary.

We use a Wiki for our current project and it works very well. It is easy to access for anyone (developers, managers, and customers) and a history can track changes, so you know what has been changed and why. Furthermore, we try to document the code in a meaningful way and document the major design decisions. We try not to document too much, e.g. minor things, as it is always hard to keep those things up-to-date and it is not worth the effort, imho.

Comment: +1 for that. That's a really great point.

Answer (score 10):

Worst for me than lack of documentation is **excess** of documentation.

Keep in mind that yes: it's really important to document your project, but also that the major part of your documentation is always at risk of **never** been read at all.

So, I think that a good starting point consist in thinking of your documentation more like something that you may use to introduce new developers to your project than an over detailed description of the inner workings of your software.

Comment: Great point, too much documentation, and you end up spending as much time maintaining the documentation as you do maintaining the project.

Comment: Give an example for a software you know and has "more than necessary documentation". Even if the documentation is not going to be read, it helps the programmers to understand the problem better and see the gaps and possible bugs.

Comment: @kami I think the point went beyond documentation not being read and into, hard to maintain.  If you make changes in 3 core functions, do you want to have to update 60 pages?  There's a trade-off and finding the balance is important.

Answer (score 6):

G'day,

Definitely use a wiki. I'd recommend TWiki as it's an excellent and extensive implementation of a wiki without being too complicated to install and manage.

Here's a couple of initial thoughts.

**Categories:**

Start off with an initial ontology of what you want to capture but

- allow people to add new categories or sub-categories as required,
- allow people to retitle (sub-)categories as required and maybe as agreed for this one so you don't get fragmentation for multiple names for basically the same thing.
- let any initial (sub-)categories wither and die if they are left empty. Do this at the end of the project as some areas may only have entries towards the end of a project.

**Tagging:**

Start using a tag cloud. BTW here's an excellent plug-in available for TWiki to start classifying content early on in the project. Retrofitting tags is almost impossible to do. Starting tagging early also allows people to search for information that may be there already rather than having the same info located in multiple places.

HTH I'll come back and add more points as I think of them.

Comment: IMHO wikis are very good for static information but if you have a project with several different versions you need versioning of the documentation too. So the documentation should flow into the branches as the source code does.

Comment: @schoetbi, i agree but that is a very specific area of the documentation. I've seen wikis work very successfully when a split happened for different versions of a project. When the split happened, new pages were created to document the individualities of the versions. That is, one page covering the common aspects and then  that page is updated with links through to the new pages that are used to specify the specific aspects of the new versions that are different.

Answer (score 3):

First and most important, have the comments written in such a way that NDoc can parse them.  This is the best way to have the code itself documented, as the developers have to change their development practices very little, and you can generate pages that explain the code without having to look at the code.

Second, getting developers to write documentation is not easy, and getting them to do it might be an exercise in futility.  This is where products like [Fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) come into play.  They will help manage the development with tickets, help track check ins, and when your done an iteration, generate release notes.

In conclusion, your best bet is to find the most effective solution that fits in with the devs existing process.  If it impacts their development process very little, they will be more likely to adopt the system.

Comment: Do developers read docs generated with NDoc? Or are they just as happy reading comments in the code itself? Also, I feel that using NDoc make people write lots of unnecessary comments in code just to have every class and method included in the generated documentation.

Comment: The project I have been working on is in java, and we comment for JDocs, and I do find that commenting getters and setters, as well as some other things, can be a bit of overkill, but at the same time, its good to get into a habit of always writing at least a sentence or two about the method.  We don't write information on every parameter passed to a function, or every return value of a function, but we always put at least 1 sentence explaining what we are doing.  And yes, as a developer, I do look at the docs, they are easier to read, and its easier to find functions.